# After Effects crashing Mac Book Pro 2019

Tags: after-effects

I'm having issues with my After Effects freezing my whole laptop and having to press the shutdown button to restart it. I have talked to two Adobe Agents and screen shared with them and neither of them could figure out what the problem was. Apparently I have sufficient memory and one of them has installed a cleaner application of some sort. I have also reinstalled After Effects. I have also cleared cache in After Effects preferences so am wondering what else I can do so that it doesn't do this. Wondering if buying more ram would work to speed up the laptop? I am not heavily dependant on this App I was just trying tutorials and wanting to have an additional skill I mostly use Illustrator and InDesign. So not to keen on investing a lot of money in something that I just want to learn at a fairly basic level.

It freezes on certain tutorial files the ones that have more keyframes but its a beginners tutorial so the animations aren't that complex so when Im editing the keyframes thats when it usually freezes.

I tried a mac desktop at work which is actually older than my laptop and it did freeze when I opened one of the files up in my tutorials it took longer but eventually happened.

Have also opened in Safemode and it still crashed, went through a series of troubleshooting things with the Adobe Agents.

This is the memory I have so far on my laptop[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it freeze or crash at a specific time or with a specific plugin? Have you opened AE in safe mode? Have you tried the same project on another Mac without issue?

Comment: @tomh have updated description :)